# Finding, moving and removing in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, find, functions, xargs

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-62-generic x86_64)

I have a directory like the following:

```
~/total/
    test1/
        test1.txt
        some_other_file_i_dont_care.py
    test2/
        test2.tex
        some_folder_i_dont_care/
    test3/
        test3.csv
```

I want to move **only the text files** out of there, and erase their parent folders (which have the **same names** as the files I'm interested in).

So the result should be this:

```
~/total/
    test1.txt
    test2.tex
    test3.csv
```

I think I'm not far from the solution with this function:

```
find ~/total/ -type f  \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.tex' -o -iname '*.csv' \)          
| xargs mv -ifile file ~/total/
```

**But then, how can I remove the remaining folders?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the two operations in one go of `find` :

```
find . -depth \( -regex '.*\.\(txt\|tex\|csv\)' -exec mv -- {} . \; \
                 -o -not -name . -delete \)
```

- `-regex '.*\.\(txt\|tex\|csv\)' -exec mv -- {} . \;` will find the files with `.txt` or `.tex` or `csv` extensions and will move those to the current directory
- `-not -name . -delete` will then remove everything else

Example :

```
total$ tree
.
├── test1
│   ├── some.py
│   └── test1.txt
├── test2
│   ├── somedir
│   └── test2.tex
└── test3
    └── test3.csv


total$ find . -depth \( -regex '.*\.\(txt\|tex\|csv\)' -exec mv -- {} . \; -o -not -name . -delete \)


total$ tree
.
├── test1.txt
├── test2.tex
└── test3.csv
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution. I'm accepting it. Nevertheless my solution it's not much longer and it has the advantage of being separated into two yunks of logical code.

Comment: @tomasyany In your answer you don't need `xargs`..`find..-exec` alone can handle unusual filenames..also it doesn't trigger ARG_MAX

Comment: It's true that it becomes more complicated, since I hace to add a `-print0` option so it would work with files with spaces. There's still one question I have: can you put confirmation question for every directory deleted? I can't with `rm -ir` for stdin reasons, but I could do it with `for i in $(find ~/test/ -type d); do rm -ir "$i"; done`

Comment: @tomasyany Yes, you can..in that case use `-exec rm -ir {} \;` instead of `-delete`